# Check for Null/Not Null in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Efficent way to write the below queries

```
where col_1 is not null and((col_2 is not null and col_3 is not null)<br/>
                                           or (col_4 is not null and Col_5 is not null)<br/>
                                           or(col_3 is not null and col_4 is not null)<br/>
                                           or(col_2 is not null and Col_5 is not null)<br/>
                                           )<br/>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
col_1 is null and ((col_2 is null and col_3 is null and col_4 is null and col_5 is null)<br/>
    or (col_2 is not null and col_3 is null and col_4 is null and col_5 is null)<br/>
    or (col_2 is  null and col_3 is not null and col_4 is null and col_5 is null)<br/>
    or (col_2 is  null and col_3 is null and col_4 is not null and col_5 is null)<br/>
    or (col_2 is  null and col_3 is null and col_4 is null and col_5 is not null)<br/>
    )<br/>
```

Comment: You should probably change your table design. Do you need help with that?

Comment: i didnt get what you meant to change the table design ?

Comment: If you're just looking for at least one not null use: `coalesce(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) is not null`. It's not clear to us which combinations you're looking for.

Comment: My condition  is to check if 2 of the 4 columns(Col_2,Col_3,Col_4,Col_5) is not null in the first query and the second query to check if 3 or more columns are null (col2,col3,col4,col5)

Comment: I mean you don't show the real content of your table (or are `col_x` the real names?), but looking at your query I guess your table design is bad and when changing it according to DB design rules, you can avoid such ugly queries.

Comment: Within the discrete math, logic the help you to simply the logic statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just map the condition to 0 and 1 so you can add up the number of matches:

```
case when col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when col3 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when col4 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when col5 is not null then 1 else 0 end = 2
```

Similarly...

```
case when col1 is null then 1 else 0 end +
case when col2 is null then 1 else 0 end +
case when col3 is null then 1 else 0 end +
case when col4 is null then 1 else 0 end +
case when col5 is null then 1 else 0 end >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the question about logic in discrete math.
For the first part, you can simply to

```
Where col1 is not null 
AND (
       (col3 is not null OR col5 is not null)
       AND
       (col4 is not null OR col2 is not null)
    )
```